# SQL Grouping Within A Table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to see if there is a way to enable me to group and sort a table without needing to develop another table for the same purpose.

The main column titles that I am wanting to deal with are `manufacturer_id, sort_order`

In my `sort_order` rows I have a couple of values with `1,2` and then the rest have `0` is there a way to show the `1,2` first then the `0` per `manufacturer_id`?

**Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_ps_products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `youtube` char(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `on_special` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sort_order` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=90 ;
```

Comment: I am a little bit uncertain of what you want. Can you show us some sample records and expected outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE2**

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM default_ps_products p
 ORDER BY manufacturer_id, 
          FIELD(COALESCE(sort_order, 0), 0),
          COALESCE(sort_order, 0)
```

Sample output:

```
| ID | MANUFACTURER_ID | SORT_ORDER |
-------------------------------------
|  2 |               1 |          1 |
|  4 |               1 |          1 |
|  3 |               1 |          2 |
|  1 |               1 |          0 |
|  5 |               1 |     (null) |
|  8 |               2 |          1 |
|  7 |               2 |          2 |
|  9 |               2 |          0 |
|  6 |               2 |          0 |
| 10 |               2 |     (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb5c4/9)** demo

Comment: Yes I am wanting it like that is there anyway to make it dynamic as there could be many values like 1,2,3,4 etc

Comment: Thanks @peterm just looking at the result in my phpMyAdmin it shows 2,1 how can I reverse it so its 1,2,3 etc

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Updated again. This version will sort by sort_order value if it's not 0 or NULL first